# Почему не используется LocalStorage?

Tags: jquery, localstorage

**Здравствуйте**

Писал код для смены стиля css через чекбокс. Задача стоит в сохранении выбранного варианта, даже если пользователь закроет браузер и выключит компьютер, по возвращению должно всё остаться как есть. LocalStorage как нельзя лучше для этого подходит. 
В голове страницы записан путь к стилю css по умолчанию.
Вот код с которым взаимодействует пользователь.

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label class="switch mt-4">
      <input type="checkbox" id="darkside" onclick="swiftCk()">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>  
   <span class="cp">Ночной режим</span>
</div>
```

А это скрипт который взаимодействует с выше описанным кодом:

```
     function swiftCk() {

        var key = localStorage.getItem('check');
        var r = (key === null) ? false : true;         
        var href = (key === null) ? 'white' : 'dark';         
        $('#darkside').attr('checked', r);
        $('#darkness').attr('href', '/panel/css/'+href+'.min.css');            

        var checkBox = document.getElementById("darkside");
        if (checkBox.checked === false){
            localStorage.removeItem('check');
            $('#darkside').attr('checked', true);
            $('#darkness').attr('href', '/panel/css/white.min.css');              
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('check', 'true');
            $('#darkside').attr('checked', false);
            $('#darkness').attr('href', '/panel/css/dark.min.css');
            //$('#darkside').removeAttr('checked');
        }

    }
```

Писал его сам. Всё работает. Есть запись в LocalStorage и сменяется путь к стилю. Всё применяется по клику.

ПРОБЛЕМА:
После перезагрузки страницы выбранная опция слетает, LocalStorage никуда не пропал. Писал код вне функции:

```
    var key = localStorage.getItem('check');
    var r = (key === '') ? false : true;         
    var href = (key === '') ? 'white' : 'dark';         
    $('#darkside').attr('checked', r);
    $('#darkness').attr('href', '/panel/css/'+href+'.min.css');
```

Это держит выбор на "dark" стиле, и не слетает, если почистить LocalStorage, возвращается "white style" но очистка LocalStorage происходит и при повторном нажатии на чекбокс.
Пожалуйста помогите разобраться где я туплю. 
**В чём моя ошибка?**

Comment: А "писал код вне функции" - это разово или он у вас на странице все таки присутствует ?

Comment: `var r = (key === '') ? false : true;`  выглядит странно. r будет true в не зависимости от хранимого в сторадже значения (если оно не пустое). getItem вернет null, а не `''` в случае отсутствия ключа

Comment: Добрый вечер @Mike - LocalStorage никуда не девается, если его не сбросить повторным нажатием, или принудительно через инспектор кода. Почему память не достаётся странице, при её наличии, вот это не понятно. Как правильно проверять, есть ключ или нету?

Comment: вы же туда "true" пишите или удаляете. так и считайте, что любое значение кроме "true" - это его отсутствие. а текущее сранение `key===''` _ВСЕГДА_ даст false, потому что у вас не может быть случая, что в сторадже лежит пустая строка

Comment: Хорошо @Mike - я понял, как проверить, что LocalStorage пустой? Я давно это делал, подзабыл уже, работало, надо проверить есть ли у ключа значение, и если нет, то вернуть значение по умолчанию, либо выбранную опцию, если ключ ЕСТЬ

Comment: В функции клика вы правильно проверяете `(key === null)`. только все равно не пойму зачем такие сложности, любое key!='ture' можно считать пустым и не парится (если других значений не ожидается)

Comment: @Mike , благодарю, я разобрался

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле функция работает если:

```
    function swiftCk() {
       var key = localStorage.getItem('check');
       var r = (key !== null) ? false : true;  
    ...
    }
```

Когда ключ не равен NULL тогда есть толк, в инспекторе кода "значение" либо пустое, либо там что-то есть. Вызываем в браузере **F12** -> **Application** -> **Local Storage** -> *open*

> Смотрим таблицу, находим ключ **"check"** - если он пустой, значит
>   ничего не применяем.